# UISearchBar setBarTintColor unrecognized selector exception in ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an exception in iOS6:

```
-[UISearchBar setBarTintColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xad94250
```

but I don't have this method in my code. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can do a conditional check to see if you are on iOS7 or lower. 
if you are on iOS6 use `tintColor` otherwise use `barTintColor` in iOS7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

barTintColor available from iOS 7 and above, so it will work for iO7 and above only

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *barTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;  // default is nil
```

For iOS 6.1 and lower you have to use

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about the properties.

```
self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```